# MVP design pattern issue in Android

Tags: java, android, oop, mvp, android-mvp

I was doing R&D on MVP and I am thinking to use this design pattern for my next project.
But I am facing a problem with this design pattern.

Please have a look at below java code.

I have a BaseActivity class

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

}
```

An Interface BaseView

```
public interface BaseView {

void showLoader();
void hideLoader();

}
```

One more interface which extends BaseView Interface to maintain relation between views

```
//Game start from here
public interface TestView extends BaseView {
    void showResult();
}
```

Here is the final Activity :

```
public class MyTestActivity extends BaseActivity implements TestView {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_test);
     }

    @Override
    public void showLoader() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hideLoader() {

    }

    @Override
    public void showResult() {

    }
}
```

2 methods showLoader() and HideLoader() from BaseView are common to every interface which extends BaseView.
that's why I keep them into BaseView. no problem till now.

Problem is: I have to implements and provider definition of these methods in every class which implements BaseView or its Child interface.

Example: Here in

```
TestActivity extends BaseActivity implements TestView
```

So to prevent this problem I implemented BaseView into BaseActivity and provider these methods definition.
But I can see BaseView is coming to TestActivity from BaseActivity(if I implement BaseView in BaseActivity)

And Also from TestView which is already implementing BaseView.
**It's my requirement TestView must extend BaseView.**
if i do not implements BaseView in BaseActivity i need to implements showLoader() and hideLoader() methods in every Activity class. right now I have 2 methods in BaseView they can be more...

Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just implement default implementation in BaseActivity. So You can override methods in childs if needs.

```
BaseActivity implements BaseView
```

Comment: It's my requirement TestView must extend BaseView .

Comment: All should works fine:

`TestView extend BaseView` --  `BaseActivity implements BaseView` --
  `TestActivity extends BaseActivity implements TestView`

Comment: In that case, BaseView will be duplicate in TestActivity and this is against of Standards.

Comment: Java **interface** just a contract to "implementing some methods" it isn't "against of Standards"

Comment: Also you can make your BaseActivity **abstract** to implement only part of BaseView methods

Answer (score 1):

How I would implement MVP is as follows.

You'd have your BaseView and BasePresenter. Then you'd have a contract between your View and Presenter which has it's own interfaces that extends your BaseView and BasePresenter, i'll show you as follows:

ExampleActivity

```
public class ExampleActivity extends BaseActivity implements ExampleContract.View {
     private ExampleContract.Presenter presenter;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);

         presenter = new ExamplePresenter(this);
         presenter.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void setPresenter(ExampleContract.Presenter presenter) {
         this.presenter = presenter;
    }
}
```

ExamplePresenter

```
public class ExamplePresenter implements ExampleContact.Presenter {
     private ExampleContract.View exampleView;

     public ExamplePresenter(ExampleContract.View exampleView) {
         this.exampleView = exampleView;
         exampleView.setPresenter(this)
     }

     @Override
     public void start() {
         //do nothing for now
     }
}
```

ExampleContract

```
public interface ExampleContract {

    interface View extends BaseView<Presenter> {

    }

    interface Presenter extends BasePresenter {

    }

}
```

BaseView

```
public interface BaseView<T> {
    void setPresenter(T presenter);
}
```

BasePresenter

```
public interface BasePresenter {
    void start();
}
```

---

So what can we take away from this and how does it all link up?

- So, if you want shared implementation for all your **contracts** (not views) i.e. every one of my views and presenters will either have a `setPresenter(T presenter)` call and `start()` call throughout the whole app add it to your `BaseView` or `BasePresenter`.
- Then in your contracts your `View` interface and `Presenter` interface (which the individual activities will be implementing, will then have it's own functionality individual to the activity you want to implement.
- Then, the Presenter is linked to the view by passing itself into the presenters constructor in `onCreate` and then inside the Presenter's constructor it'll callback to the view by setting the presenter. They are both now assigned to each other through a binding contract. All you have to do now is add the methods to your contract either in the View interface and the Presenter interface.

Comment: I am doing exactly same, again the problem with BaseView and ExampleContract.View, in Activity I have to implement all methods.

Comment: I have written less code if BaseActivity will provider definition of BaseView methods.

Comment: MVP is not about writing less code, it's about writing testable code. You can have a protected method in your BaseActivity class and call it from your children when you need it, if you're concerned about writing more code. But, you'll need a contract between your presenter and your view. Or as senya says above make the base abstract and choose what to implement

Comment: Okay completely agree with your point. But i dont want to give defination of BaseView methods in every Activity. Its not about the code size its about the code duplicacy. Any suggestion..